# Uninstall Hyperledger Composer

Tags: docker, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

How do I completely uninstall Hyperledger Composer (and underlying Hyperledger Fabric), including all dependencies, docker images and node/npm modules?

I had followed the following setup while installing: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html

I have done the following already:

```
npm uninstall -g composer-cli
npm uninstall -g composer-rest-server
npm uninstall -g generator-hyperledger-composer
npm uninstall -g yo
npm uninstall -g composer-playground
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have the npm modules sorted.

To remove all docker containers and images:

`docker kill $(docker ps -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)`

Remove composer cards folder `rm -rf ~/.composer`

To remove the scripts and tools to create Fabric: `rm -rf ~/.fabric-tools`

To remove docker-compose: `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

To remove docker: `sudo apt-get remove docker-ce`

Check the "prereqs-ubuntu.sh" script to see the other "apt-get install" commands and see if you want to remove them too.

Answer (score 2):

Run these commands below to stop and remove container processes.

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

To stop and remove images completely run the following commands

```
docker stop $(docker images -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)
```

To check if anything is there ,

```
docker ps -a 
docker images -a
```